# ASP.NET MVC5: how to pass AssemblyVersion parameter to requirejs urlArgs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs

Simple as that: In ASP.NET MVC5 view, how do I pass parameter to requirejs urlArgs? I would like to read assembly version like this...

```
var assemblyVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                                .GetName()
                                                .Version
                                                .ToString();
```

... and pass it to requirejs to bust cache and load the latest version.
Tried various things but still unable to properly reach the requirejs configuration from the Razor markup :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep a hidden input element in cshtml and set it's value using

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

then in js

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + document.getElementById('yourinputelementid').value
});
```

Comment: Ha, turns out I was retarded enough to assume there is nothing in the DOM when require.config() executes :D This is a correct answer. And I found another (preferred) solution to avoid stuffing the dom with the metadata such as version number...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found:

```
example.cshtml

@{
  var assemblyVersion = typeof(SimpleMessages.Web.MvcApplication).Assembly
                                                                 .GetName()
                                                                 .Version
                                                                 .ToString();
}

@section scripts {
  <script>
      require.config({ urlArgs: "v=@assemblyVersion" });
      @Html.RequireJs("/Scripts/main.js", "/Scripts/My/chat-ko.js");
  </script>
}
```

This way there is nothing in the DOM, and assembly version is dynamically properly created.

HTH